# Coinbase API list real deposits

Tags: coinbase-api

I was looking into the coinbase API to find a way to list all deposits made into a specific account but the follow doesn't work for all cases:

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id/deposits
```

If the user purchased a share of BTC using a credit card for example the record won't be in deposits but in buys.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Coinbase [list-deposits](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#list-deposits) and [list-withdraws](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#list-withdrawals) api calls don't appear to return crypto currency transactions.  They only appear to work for fiat.  I can't find any docs to verify this but from my tests that appears to be the case.

However, you can see your crypto deposits and withdrawals if you use [list-transactions](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#list-transactions) api call.